# Weird things happening when making image get bigger on mouse hover in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, image-resizing

I am making a scene where there is a thumbs-up image that is supposed to get bigger on mouse hover, and shrink back to normal size when the mouse is no longer hovering.

This is how I make the thumbs-up image:

```py
thumbs_up_image = pygame.image.load("./plz_like.png")
thumbs_up_rect = thumbs_up_image.get_rect(topleft=(screen.get_width() // 2 - thumbs_up_image.get_width() + 75,
                                                   screen.get_height() // 2 + thumbs_up_image.get_height() - 225))
```

And this is how I make it get bigger:

```py
if thumbs_up_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
    thumbs_up_image = pygame.transform.scale(thumbs_up_image,
                                             [n + 50 for n in thumbs_up_image.get_size()])
    thumbs_up_rect = thumbs_up_image.get_rect()
```

This is how the image is blited:

```py
screen.blit(thumbs_up_image, thumbs_up_rect)
```

The problem is that when I hover on the thumbs-up image, it first goes to the top-left corner of the screen. Then, when I hover on it again, it gets super big and pixelated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out by myself.

This is how I do it:

First, I prepared a bigger version of the image and it's rect: (as shown below)

```py
big_thumbs_image = pygame.transform.scale(thumbs_up_image, [i + 50 for i in thumbs_up_image.get_size()])

big_thumbs_image_rect = thumbs_up_image.get_rect(
    topleft=(screen.get_width() // 2 - thumbs_up_image.get_width() + 55,
             screen.get_height() // 2 + thumbs_up_image.get_height() - 250))
```

Then, when the small image's rect collides with the mouse, blit the bigger image:

```py
if thumbs_up_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
    screen.blit(big_thumbs_image, big_thumbs_image_rect)
```

Comment: There's no need to apologize. Answering your own question is a completely legitimate use of Stack Overflow if you know the answer, and nobody else has yet provided an adequate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this pygame function:

```py
pygame.transform.rotozoom(Surface, angle, scale)
```

I also had some issues with pixilation in a game but it seemed to work with this.

Comment: How do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing the code that actually renders the image to the screen.; But basically: you are not saving the original size - at each hover event it will grow and grow (and it will grow once per frame, if that code is run in the mainloop).

You need a variable to hold the original image, one to tell your code the image has already been resized, and an `else` clause on this `if` to restore the original image: pygame won't do that for you.

Also, when you use the `get_rect` for the image, its top-left position will always be "0, 0" - you have to translate this top-left corner to a suitable coordinate- getting the rectangle center of the original sprite (wherever the data of its location on the screen is kept), and setting the same center on the new rect should work.

And finally, prefer "rotozoom" than "scale" - Pygame documentation is clear that the second method uses better algorithms for scaling.